# Formula Excel 3 Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

[image]

how the formula used in the following picture. I want 
if `A1` is smaller than `B1` and `C1` the result is "Good", 
if `B1` is smaller than `A1` and `C1` the result is "Fair", and
if `C1` is smaller than `A1` and `B1` the result is "Bad".

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any good reason for your question to depend on an image. Surely you can include the relevant layout in the question itself. In any event, a straightforward nested `If()` function should work. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried 2 conditions succesfully, =IF(A1<B1,"Good","Bad"). but if 3 conditions are still unknown

Comment: `=If(A1 < Min(B1,C1),"Good", If(B1 < Min(A1,C1),"Fair","Bad"))` ?

Comment: yes, thank you. it's work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is without if function. Also this is bit shorter than the if function above.

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(SMALL(A1:C1,1),A1:C1,0),"Good","Fair","Bad")
```